# boundary differential equation

Tags: equation-solving, differential-equations, difference-equations

```
eqns[a_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ,  γ_?NumericQ] := 
  {Derivative[4][f][y] - 2 Derivative[2][f][y] a^2 + 
     a^2 (-r y + a^2) f[y] == 0, f[0] == 0, 
   Derivative[3][f][0] - Derivative[1][f][0] a^2 == 0, 
   Derivative[1][f][0] == 1, Derivative[2][f][0] == γ};

sol[a_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ, γ_?NumericQ] := 
  NDSolveValue[eqns[a, r, γ], f, {y, 0, 1}, Method -> "BDF", 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity, InterpolationOrder -> All]
a = 5;
γ = 1;

DFend[r_?NumericQ] := D[f[y] /. sol[r], {y, 1}] /. y -> 5

sol[r_?NumericQ] = FindRoot[DFend[r] = 1, {r, 1}]
```

Hello everybody, T want to find the value of `r` and plot it with this condition `,y=1,f[1] = 0, f''[1] = 0`

but the problem I can't find `r`
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem can be solved as follows.

```
a = 5;
γ = 1;

eqns = {Derivative[4][f][y] - 2 Derivative[2][f][y] a^2 + 
        a^2 (-r y + a^2) f[y] == 0, f[0] == 0, 
        Derivative[3][f][0] - Derivative[1][f][0] a^2 == 0, 
        Derivative[1][f][0] == 1, Derivative[2][f][0] == γ};

sol =  ParametricNDSolveValue[eqns, {f, f'}, {y, 0, 5}, {r}];

Quiet@FindRoot[sol[r][[2]][5] == 1, {r, -.5}]
(* {r -> -0.421472} *)
```

It also may be helpful to plot `f'[5]` as a function of `r`.

```
Plot[sol[r][[2]][5], {r, -1, 1}, AxesLabel -> {r, f'}]
```

[image]

The changes made to obtain this result are:

- Do not define `eqns` and `sol` as functions, which is unnecessary and creates complications.
- Use `ParametricNDSolveValue` instead of `NDSolveValue` to accommodate the parameter `r`.
- Let `ParametricNDSolveValue` determine `f'` for improved accuracy and to simplify the subsequent root-finding process.
- Replace `=` by `==` in `FindRoot`.

Comment: thanks a lot sir,how i can see the plot,what i should write

Comment: eqns[a_?NumericQ, 
   r_?NumericQ, \[Gamma]_?
    NumericQ] := {Derivative[4][f][y] - 2 Derivative[2][f][y] a^2 + 
     a^2 (-r y + a^2) f[y] == 0, f[0] == 0, 
   Derivative[3][f][0] - Derivative[1][f][0] a^2 == 0, 
   Derivative[1][f][0] == 1, Derivative[2][f][0] == \[Gamma]};

sol[a_?NumericQ, r_?NumericQ, \[Gamma]_?NumericQ] := 
 NDSolveValue[eqns[a, r, \[Gamma]], f, {y, 0, 1}, Method -> "BDF", 
  MaxSteps -> Infinity, InterpolationOrder -> All]

eval = sol[1, 2, 3];

Plot[eval[y], {y, 0, 1}]     and with this algoritm how i can found the valure of 'r'

Comment: @ImedBouRogaà  Why try to find more complicated and potentially less reliable approaches?   In general, it is better to seek simpler approaches.

Comment: @bbgodfrey Now I remember that old friend of mine, Occam.